# How to forecast for future dates using time series forecasting in Python?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima

I am new to time series forecasting and have made the following model:

```
df = pd.read_csv('timeseries_data.csv', index_col="Month")

# ARMA
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARMA
from random import random
# contrived dataset
data = df
# fit model
model = ARMA(data, order=(2, 1))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=False)
# make prediction
yhat = model_fit.predict()
print(yhat)
```

The above code predicts for the data points in df. But what should I do if I want to predict for some future date? For example: For the entire year of 2022?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, it was actually very simple:

```
arma_df = model_fit.predict(start='2020-01-01', end='2023-12-01')
```

Comment: Another option is to use `model_fit.forecast('2023-12-01')`.

Comment: Its not works at all